# How do I get pandas to read elements in a series as null?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series. Here are the value counts:

```
tafe_resignations['job_dissatisfaction'].value_counts(dropna = False)

Output:
-                      268
Job Dissatisfaction     62
NaN                      8
Name: job_dissatisfaction, dtype: int64
```

Note the NaN values are actually null (they don't appear if I don't use dropna = False)
I want to use map to either change these values to True/False/Remain as NaN.My code for this is:

```
def job_satisfactions(element):
    if not element:
        return np.nan
    elif element == '-':
        return False
    else:
        return True

test = tafe_resignations['job_dissatisfaction'].map(job_satisfactions)
test
```

Every time I run this, all null values are replaced by True. I've tried many different ways to write the first argument to return np.nan, none have worked. What should I do? One more thing,
the else-clause needs to return True, so I can't switch things around to make that return np.nan.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `pd.isnull()`?

```
if pd.isnull(element):
    return np.nan
```

Comment: Yes thank you! That is very obvious to me now, but I was thinking to myself element.isnull() which I knew wouldn't work.

Comment: Great, sorry for assuming you did the import as `import pandas as pd`.